# build.phonegap.com doesnt care my config.xml

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

My folder structure

```
app
- config.xml
- icon.png
- res
- - icon
- - screen
- www
- - index.html
.......
```

I m uploading my app to build.phonegap.com, 
in my config.xml file i m changing description and upload new zip file to the build.phonegap.com but i see the old one, it is like cached. 
Also in config.xml i have this line

```
<icon src="icon.png" />
```

and others

```
<platform name="ios">
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon.png" platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
```

but still web page doesnt show the icon
( i m using framework7 )

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure but maybe you are having issues because you are mixing the 2 ways of specifying an icon together. You are using the platform attribute inside the platform tag. It's explained here in more detail:
http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/icons-and-splash/

Try the following definition as used in the phonegap starter project:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml

```
 <icon src="icon.png" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" />
<icon src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png"     gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />
<icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
<icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

<!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png"      gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"              gap:platform="blackberry" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"         gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"           gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg"      gap:platform="winphone" />
```

An also be careful with names of your icons, they are case sensitive.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks i ll try that.
What about the changing description in the config.xml, its not affecting the app?

Comment: do you mean the <description> tag?